# C++ force specific type for variadic template (even concepts seem not to work)

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++-concepts

If we have a constructor that accepts 3 parameters of type bool:

```
struct BoolOnly {
    BoolOnly (bool b1, bool b2, bool b3)
    {}
};
```

The compiler validates that we are actually calling it with boolean arguments:

```
BoolOnly b1 {0,1,1};    //ok
BoolOnly b2 {0,1,4};    //error: narrowing conversion of ‘4’ from ‘int’ to ‘bool’
```

It gives a compiler error, if a values is outside the range for boolean, which is perfectly OK.

Now the problem: I want to have a variadic template constructor, which I want to accept only arguments of type bool. In other words, I want to be able to pass an initializer consisting only of 0s or 1s. And get a compiler error if I pass something else

```
struct BoolOnlyExactVariadic {
    template<typename... Args>
    BoolOnlyExactVariadic (Args... args)
    {}
};
```

Here we cannot specify any type of the parameters. this constructor accepts any count of arguments of any types. There is still no support in C++ for homogeneous variadic template arguments.

The most advanced thing we have are concepts - they seem to be designed for setting restrictions on variadic template arguments. So, Let's try with std::same_as

```
template<typename T>
concept BooleanExact = std::same_as<T, bool>;

struct BoolOnlyExact {
    template<typename... Args>
    BoolOnlyExact (BooleanExact auto... b)
    {}
};
```

But the problem is that this template does not even accept values that are in the bool range:

```
BoolOnlyExact t2 {0,0,0}; //note: the expression ‘(... && BooleanExact<auto:12>) [with auto:12 = {int, int, int}]’ evaluated to ‘false’
```

The arguments get converted to int, which is not exact conversion to bool.
Let's try then with std::convertible_to:

```
template<typename T>
concept BooleanConv = std::convertible_to<T, bool>;


struct BoolOnlyConv {
    template<typename... Args>
    BoolOnlyConv (BooleanConv auto... b)
    {}
};
```

Now the compilation succeeds, but there is no validation for argument values:

```
BoolOnlyConv t1 {4,4,5}; //ok, but we want to validate them
```

even if the values are outside the boolean range. (No idea why the compiler thinks that '5' is convertible to bool).

Is there any C++20/C++23 way to validate a variadic init list of bools at compile time, like the first example? Other than manually writing a function with 15 arguments? The problem here is that there may be cases with more arguments (for example, 9 or 25), for which separate functions will be needed?

Comment: The point of a variadic template is to allow variable types. To just accept an arbitrary number of `bool`s, I'd use an argument of type `std::initializer_list<bool>`. It'll require an extra pair of braces at the call site, like `foo({true, false, true, true, false});`, but that seems like a pretty small price to pay for something that directly expresses your intent.

Comment: Also note that `0` and `1` are `int` literals that can be converted to `bool`. The boolean literals are `false` and `true`, respectively.

Comment: Looks like you want `type_is` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72823552/4342498)

Comment: `template <typename ... X> requires (std::is_same_v<X, bool> && ...)` (you cannot use 1 and 0 there, only literals true and false).

Comment: @Nuclear: "*The compiler validates that we are actually calling it with boolean arguments:*" No, it doesn't. It validates that the literals are convertible to a boolean type without narrowing. Those literals are not "boolean arguments"; they're *integers*.

Comment: @NathanOliver: That won't actually help. Deduction happens before checking against the validity of a concept, and `0` will always be deduced as an `int`.

Comment: @Nuclear: "*No idea why the compiler thinks that '5' is convertible to bool*" That's because it is. Any integer is implicitly convertible to `bool`; integers that are not 0 are converted to the boolean value `true`.

Comment: As others have already pointed out, `1` and `0` are of type `int`. If you want a `bool`, use `true` and `false`. If you want `int` to be a valid argument, provided it's a `1` or `0`, you can only do a runtime check (unless you use `constexpr` or `consteval`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would forget the idea of passing `0`,`1` as bools, use `true`,`false`, and check the type with `std::same_as<bool>`.

The only other options I see are:

- If all your bools are constexpr, and so is the constructor body, you can make the constructor `consteval` and check the integers at compile-time to make sure they're in range.
- Or perhaps create a `template <bool...> struct BoolList {};` and pass that to the constructor. But that changes the call syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Not a great solution... but if you have an upper limit (99, in the following example) for the number of bools... you can recursively add the required only boolean constructors

We can start from a trivial struct that receive a number as template parameter, ignore it and set a `using` type as `bool`

```
template <std::size_t>
struct getBool
 { using type = bool; };
```

Then you can create a template recursive class `AddC` (for "add constructor") to add boolean only constructors

```
template <typename>
struct AddC;

template <std::size_t ... Is>
struct AddC<std::index_sequence<Is...>>
  : public AddC<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is)-1u>>
{
  using AddC<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is)-1u>>::AddC;

  AddC (typename getBool<Is>::type ... as)
  { };
};

// to stop the recursion
template <>
struct AddC<std::index_sequence<>>
{ };
```

Now `BoolOnlyExactVariadic` simply become

```
struct BoolOnlyExactVariadic
  : public AddC<std::make_index_sequence<100u>>
{ 
  using AddC<std::make_index_sequence<100u>>::AddC;
};
```

The following is a full compiling example (except for the `t3` variable that gives a narrowing compilation error).

```
#include <utility>

template <std::size_t>
struct getBool
 { using type = bool; };

template <typename>
struct AddC;

template <std::size_t ... Is>
struct AddC<std::index_sequence<Is...>>
  : public AddC<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is)-1u>>
{
  using AddC<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is)-1u>>::AddC;

  AddC (typename getBool<Is>::type ... as)
  { };
};

// to stop the recursion
template <>
struct AddC<std::index_sequence<>>
{ };

struct BoolOnlyExactVariadic
  : public AddC<std::make_index_sequence<100u>>
{ 
  using AddC<std::make_index_sequence<100u>>::AddC;
};

int main()
{
  BoolOnlyExactVariadic t1 {0, 1, 0};             // compile
  BoolOnlyExactVariadic t2 {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0};    // compile
  BoolOnlyExactVariadic t3 {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2}; // compilation error
}
```